# How to use revealedPrefs package?

Tags: r

So I had earlier asked this question without providing a `MWE`. Specific to what I wanted to understand, consider that I have `510` observations. All the `510` subjects make `10` choices between bundles of goods each. The `revealedprefs` package helps compute the economic rationality of choices made between bundles as provided by the Axioms of Revealed Preferences.

However, I am not able to identify who of the subjects violated a given axiom of revealed preference. consider an `MWE` of `13` subjects making `10` choices as in the `data.frame`:

```
  demand1 price1 demand2 price2 demand3 price3 demand4 price4 demand5 price5 demand6 price6 demand7 price7 demand8 price8 demand9 price9 demand10 price10
1    20.00   0.33   40.00   0.50   45.00   2.00   30.00   2.00   20.00   3.00   40.00   1.00   30.00   1.00   10.00   0.25   10.00   0.50    10.00    4.00
2     0.00   1.00    0.00   3.00    0.00   0.33    5.00   2.00    0.00   4.00    0.00   2.00    4.00   0.25    0.00   1.00    0.00   0.50     0.00    0.50
3    20.00   3.00   10.00   0.50   30.00   2.00   25.00   0.50    0.00   1.00    0.00   1.00   20.00   0.50   40.00   4.00    5.00   0.25    10.00    0.33
4    10.00   0.33   10.00   2.00    0.00   4.00    0.00   1.00    0.00   2.00    0.00   0.50    0.00   1.00    0.00   0.50    0.00   3.00     0.00    0.25
5    20.00   1.00   20.00   4.00    5.00   0.25   10.00   3.00    3.00   0.33   20.00   2.00   20.00   0.50   30.00   2.00   15.00   0.50    10.00    1.00
7     2.00   0.33    2.00   0.25    1.00   0.50    1.00   4.00    2.00   2.00    1.00   1.00    1.00   0.50    1.00   1.00   10.00   3.00     1.00    2.00
8    20.00   0.25   10.00   0.33   25.00   2.00   30.00   1.00   40.00   2.00   50.00   1.00   20.00   0.50   25.00   0.50   30.00   3.00    30.00    4.00
10   20.00   3.00   30.00   2.00   40.00   2.00   10.00   0.50   40.00   1.00   15.00   0.50   10.00   1.00   10.00   4.00   10.00   4.00    10.00    0.25
11   15.00   0.50   20.00   1.00   15.00   2.00   30.00   2.00   20.00   0.50   10.00   4.00   10.00   0.25    0.00   3.00   30.00   1.00    10.00    0.33
12   10.00   3.00   10.00   0.33   30.00   1.00   40.00   1.00   10.00   0.25   20.00   0.50   25.00   2.00   20.00   2.00   25.00   0.50    20.00    4.00
13   20.00   1.00   20.00   4.00    5.00   0.25   10.00   3.00   40.00   0.33   10.00   2.00    0.00   0.50   25.00   2.00   20.00   0.50    10.00    1.00
14    0.00   0.33    0.00   1.00    0.00   0.50    0.00   3.00    0.00   2.00    0.00   0.50    0.00   0.25    0.00   1.00    5.00   2.00     5.00    4.00
15   15.00   0.50   10.00   4.00   50.00   1.00   40.00   0.50   20.00   3.00   10.00   0.33   10.00   0.25   20.00   1.00   20.00   0.50    30.00    2.00
```

We then need to ensure that the demand data frame and the price data frame are separate as required for `revealedPrefs` package. I use this code to seperate the entries and name them accordingly as in `revealedprefs`;

```
odd_indexes<-seq(1,19,2)
even_indexes<-seq(2,20,2)

demandmwe <- mwefinal[1:13, odd_indexes,1]
pricemwe <- mwefinal[1:13, even_indexes,1]

garpymwe <- list(D = demandmwe, P = pricemwe)
```

this way, the object `garpymwe` consists of a list of two `data.frames` named `D` and `P`. On the `revealedprefs` package;

```
#Testing Garp
install.packages("revealedPrefs")
library(revealedPrefs)
summary(checkGarp(garpymwe$D, garpymwe$P))
```

All works super and I can get results that there are violations of the Generalised Axioms of Revealed Preferences (GARP).

```
GARP rationality test: violation found.
  Method: Depth-first search with tabu list.
  Afriat parameter: 1 (no optimization error allowed)

  Violating observations: 2 > 12 > 2 
                        : (direct preferences)

  Other axioms:
  * WARP      : violated (symmetry of direct preferences, unequal quantities).
  * SARP      : violated (symmetry of indirect preferences, unequal quantities).
```

The only thing I am not able to understand is who exactly violates the axioms? Cleary there is the statement on `Violating observations: 2 > 12 > 2` which I am not able to really interpret. I would want to retrieve a list of GARP violators for further analysis on how severe their individual violations are.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you done so far? Please provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank you @jaySf for the challenge. I have tried to first put my head around the use of the package and now I can provide a MWE. Consider the edited form of the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually no point in asking "who are the Garp violators", and especially "how severe are their individual violations", because Garp (and Sarp) are mostly used to check for violating **cycles** of preferences.

Say for example that there are three bundles X1, X2, X3, and that the direct preferences are :

- X1 prefered to X2 (but X2 not prefered to X1)
- X2 prefered to X3 (but X3 not prefered to X2)
- X3 prefered to X1 (but X1 not prefered to X3)

In this case, there is no Warp violation (no symmetry in direct preferences), but there is a Sarp/Garp violation (X1 indirectly prefered to X3, X3 directly prefered to X1).

Removing any of the three bundles removes the violating cycle, and none of the three bundles can be said to be "more violating" than the others.

Furthermore, the Garp/Sarp functions in the *revealedPrefs* package only report the first violating cycle they find (if any), not all the possible violating cycles.

Comment: Thanks @jubo for the above answer. Probably why it matters to me on why I want to know the violators is because am using a randomised experiment for which I want to determine whether disturbances introduced in the experiment can cause violations in the axioms or revealed preferences. Again, one would want to see how existing violations fair with the adjustments of the CCEI and the C - Pendakur version. Are there more irrational choices in the treatment group that there are in the placebo? Thanks though for this!